# How to play videos from the web like youtube in kivy

Tags: android, python, video, stream, kivy

I really want to create a kivy app that lets me view videos from certain web links. How can I go about doing this, Like having a link to a video then play it in Kivy? I already read the documentation and I don't get it. Please help.

Comment: See documentation: [Video player — Kivy 1.8.1-dev documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.videoplayer.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Video`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.video.html) and [`VideoPlayer`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.videoplayer.html) widgets are both capable of playing streaming videos from the web. Here's a simple example of playing a video from the web:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

root = Builder.load_string('''
VideoPlayer:
    source: 'http://www.debone.com/VivVilConGminorRV578.mpg'
''')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

This will work for any supported streaming media type. Note, however, that YouTube does not provide streaming URLs. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685982/embed-youtube-video-in-kivy/24686687#24686687) to a question which was specifically asking about YouTube.

Comment: Question - does Kivy have the ability to be embedded on a webpage and receive a stream from OBS (attempt to get away from FB, YT, Twitch, etc)?