# python module ffpyplayer showing or displaying video frames to screen

Tags: python, python-2.7, video, ffmpeg

Using python module ffpyplayer, How can I see the frames or get the img object to display or show the video image/frames to the screen?, in the tutorial that I followed, it seems very simple, it reads the frames and plays oudio but (does not display) any video image or frame to the screen, only if I add the (print img, t) will print the frame info to the screen but not video image is displayed on the screen.

I being following tutorials from: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ffpyplayer, and here: http://matham.github.io/ffpyplayer/player.html, and searched google but the only relevant results point to the same info, I am somewhat new to programming and python, and so maybe I am missing something that seems to be very simple but I can't figure it out myself.

I am using: windows 7 64bit, python 2.7.11 32bit.

Any Help will be appreciated thank you very much.

```
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer

vid = 'test_video.flv'
player = MediaPlayer(vid)
val = ''
while val != 'eof':
    frame, val = player.get_frame()
    if val != 'eof' and frame is not None:
        img, t = frame
        print img, t     #This prints the image object
        # display img    #This does nothing!
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59611075/how-would-i-go-about-playing-a-video-stream-with-ffpyplayer/59628167#59628167) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Kivy already provides such a video player, based on ffpyplayer, for you.
It also has the necessary threads already setup for you, to deal with buttons, file reading, audio and timing.
Check this page:
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.videoplayer.html

To install kivy:
https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html

Then you might wish to take a look at the code in:

> << python_path >>\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\videoplayer.py

That example could be rather complex, so you can also look at this url:
[How to play videos from the web like youtube in kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976221/how-to-play-videos-from-the-web-like-youtube-in-kivy)

Finally, in case Kivy complains that you only have opengl 1.1 (as happened to me), you might try adding the following lines to your code:

> from kivy.config import Config
>   Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')

These solved the problem to me.